# How to set awesome's wibox visible only for certain tags?

Tags: window-manager, awesome

I'd like to have special wiboxes for certain tags like multimedia, development. I couldn't find any option in wibox for that.

I think it can be done using some event handlers and show/hide it manually, but isn't it implemented in some module and if not what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any ready-to-use modules, but I built something like that with event handlers. First you initialize your wibox as usual. Then make it invisible:

```
your_wibox.visible = false
```

Then add the signal handler for showing it to the tag(s) on which it should be visible:

```
your_tag:add_signal("property:selected", function(tag)
        your_wibox.visible = tag.selected
end)
```

This triggers, whenever the `selected` property of the tag changes, so the wibox' visibility changes with the visibility of the tag.

I don't think, that putting that into a module could make it much shorter.