# Awesome wm wibox visible just in one tag

Tags: window-manager, awesome, lua

I want to leave visible wibox1 only one of my tags.

I try use this code:

```
your_tag:add_signal("property:selected", function(tag)
        your_wibox.visible = tag.selected
end)
```

But no have success.

This is my config:

```
 wibox1 = wibox({width = 190 , height = 30, x = 40, y = 180, screen = 1 })
 wibox1.visible = false
 onlinef = blingbling.text_box({ height = 30, width= 100, v_margin = 5, font="Xirod", font_size = "10", text_color = "#00BFFF", background_text_border = "#000000",
})
 onlinef:set_text(" offline attacks ")
 wibox1:set_widget(onlinef)

 awful.key({ modkey }, "h", function () wibox1.visible=true end),
 awful.key({ modkey }, "h", function () wibox1.visible=false end),

tags = {
 names  = {
         '⌥  web',
         '⌥  Analistas',
         '⌥  Sniffing',
         '⌥  Engenharia',
         '⌥  Hardware',
         '⌥  system',
         '⌥  anony me',
         '⌥  ataques',
           },
 layout = {
      layouts[10],  --WEB
      layouts[2],   --MULTIMIDIA
      layouts[8],   --HACKING
      layouts[10],  --FREE
      layouts[4],   --FREE
      layouts[5],   --LINUX
      layouts[10],  --EDITING
      layouts[1],   --PROCESS
          }
       }
```

Comment: You may find the answer here, if you haven't already: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53922/how-to-set-awesomes-wibox-visible-only-for-certain-tags