# Awesome WM - Toggle Hide / Show Wibox

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, awesome, lua

How can I implement a function so that pressing a key toggles between hiding & showing the wibox?

I've found this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53922/how-to-set-awesomes-wibox-visible-only-for-certain-tags) but either the code doesn't work anymore or I'm not implementing it right.

The code from the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome#Hide_/_show_wibox) doesn't work either. I'm not familiar with lua so maybe I'm just implementing it really wrong and it's not just a matter of copy & paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want correct myself, the code from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome#Hide_/_show_wibox) works perfectly fine, the only caveat is that you need to include that code inside the globalkeys array. Now is working as intended.